# Problemas al llenar datatable ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, datatables, webforms

Estoy teniendo un problemita al llenar un datatable desde un WebMethod. El asunto es que en la consola del navegador llega el array y el datatable en cada columna muestra [object Object] de esta forma: [image: Asp.net]

Este es el WebMethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static List<Persona> ListarPersonas()
    {
        List<Persona> Lista = null;

        try
        {
            Lista = PersonaBL.getInstance().ListarPersonas();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Lista = new List<Persona>();
        }
        return Lista;
    }
```

Y este es el código js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'FrmPersona.aspx/ListarPersonas',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
        $.each(data, function (data) {
            var body = "<tr>";
            body += "<td>" + { data: [0] } + "</td>";
            body += "<td>" + { data: [1] } + "</td>";
            body += "<td>" + { data: [2] } + "</td>";
            body += "<td>" + { data: [3] } + "</td>";
            body += "</tr>";
            $("#datatable").append(body);
        })
        $("#datatable").DataTable(tabla);
    }
});
```

¿Alguna solución? ya no se qué hacer, he buscado por todas partes y sigo sin poder llenarlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estas accediendo correctamente a tu array de objetos. Debes corregir tu código js de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'FrmPersona.aspx/ListarPersonas',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var body = "<tr>";
            body += "<td>" + { data[index].propiedad} + "</td>"; //Reemplazar propiedad
            body += "<td>" + { data[index].propiedad} + "</td>";//Reemplazar propiedad
            body += "<td>" + { data[index].propiedad} + "</td>";//Reemplazar propiedad
            body += "<td>" + { data[index].propiedad} + "</td>";//Reemplazar propiedad
            body += "</tr>";
            $("#datatable").append(body);
        })
        $("#datatable").DataTable(tabla);
    }
});
```

**Importante: Debes reemplazar "propiedad" por el nombre de las propiedades que deseas mostrar. Por ejemplo en la imagen puedo ver que una se llama "IdPersona" y otra "Nombre".**  Por otro lado también podrías reemplazar `data[index].propiedad` por `value.propiedad` y seguiría funcionando. Puede leer la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) para comprender como funciona. Saludos!